# What are the differences between Linux and OSX's filesystem?

Tags: linux, macos, filesystems, installation

As a long-time OSX user and noob programmer, the majority of programs I've installed have been done so using a dmg file that takes care of distributing source code to my computer's file system and compiling code when necessary. However as I spend more and more time in the Terminal I find that I want to install awesome stuff that comes to me as a tar.gz file.

I recognize that there's a high degree of variability as to what follows once one unzips (untars?) said file into a directory of source code, but I've found the majority of directions out there are for people running Ubuntu or some Linux variant and that the names of directories in my filesystem as a OSX user don't quite match.

For example, it seems like files placed in the Users directory that is located in the root directory of OSX are instead placed into /home. I'm wondering if there are other differences to be aware re: where to place sourcecode.

In my case, I am attempting to install figlet and it tells me to place some files in /usr/games (thought I don't have games) and then edit the makefile to point to these paths. One of the paths is to a .dir file, is that the same as a directory?

Sorry if this is overwrought, I just hate sudo-ing when I don't know for certain what I'm doing is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you install anything that is not from Apple - i.e. local variations and versions - in /usr/local to keep it separate, and then you can have more relaxed permissions on there. That is the approach `homebrew` adopts too and it is a brilliant way of installing extra packages on OSX which I would recommend - after lots of frustration trying to hand-install stuff myself!

I din't know `figlet` but homebrew seems to [here](http://brewformulas.org/Figlet).

Answer (score 1):

The above answer by Mark is now outdated for Apple Silicon w/ Big Sur filesystems. Homebrew now has a default install directory of `/opt/homebrew` on these machines because the tool uses pre-built binaries rather than source-built bottles.

> You can still install anywhere you want. However, a number of bottles
> (pre-built binary packages) will not work for you if you don't install
> in /opt/homebrew.

The keyword here is *pre-built*. Pre-built packages need to be cross-compiled separately for ARM architecture machines and many formulae only support CISC architectures. Homebrew have wanted to migrate away from `/usr/local` before the ARM announcement but delayed the migration because it's a breaking change. Now that lots of pre-built binaries are no longer working, the migration is a good idea to fix some installation issues (reasons outlined below).

After the M1s were released, the filesystem is now more secure with The [*Secure Enclave*](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secf020d1074/1/web/1) and a hardened runtime. This means that binaries that haven't been code signed have fewer permissions to run. This is a problem for lots of brew formulae that have not been notarized. This is not a problem for Big Sur on Intel macs ([Source](https://eclecticlight.co/2021/02/18/code-signing-requirements-for-scripts-and-apps-in-big-sur/)). This tightening of the filesystem means that `/usr/local` may not be appropriate anymore for M1.

`/opt` is reserved for the installation of add-on application software packages ([Source](https://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES)) whereas the `/usr/local` hierarchy is for use by the system administrator when installing software locally ([Source](https://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY)). Thus, in theory, they should both work well for local installations.

However, M1 macs require root permissions for Homebrew `/usr/local/` installations.

Installing formulae into the `/opt/homebrew` directory is now *more permissive* than`/usr/local` on M1 machines because we don't need to use `sudo` when installing homebrew or its packages. It's always best to avoid using `sudo` for binary installations because otherwise you are not protected from elevated access malware attacks.

I would agree to install anything that is not from Apple - i.e. local variations and versions in a separate area with relaxed permissions, however, the location should be `/opt/` now for M1 machines. Homebrew `casks` are third-party and not verified, so be careful installing these binaries, and in general for running third-party software.

More details [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/440).